# mySQL search combinations of a pattern?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, combinations

Say i have a single entry in ONE column that is:

```
apples oranges pears
```

(assume it can be a infnite amount of fruits, but im just using 3)

I use the search box to search for "apples oranges" and passes the string in the $fruit variable.
My search comes up using:

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE fruitcolumn LIKE '%$fruit%'
```

However when i search for "oranges apples" or "apples pears", no results come up because the pattern doesn't match any entries. Is there an easy way to search all combinations of patterns?

Ty.

Comment: you forgot to use column name

Comment: yea it's just typo sorry

Comment: it is one entry in one column

Comment: If `fruitcolumn` contains some arbitrary text then consider to use full text search. If on the other hand these *fruits* are some sort of entity's characteristics then **stop** (don't store delimited values in the database) and normalize your data by creating many-to-many table `entity_fruits`.

Comment: @peterm thanks FULL TEXT SEARCH was what i was looking for. I can accept as answer if you post as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `fruit column` contains some arbitrary text then consider to use [Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html).

If on the other hand these `fruits` are some sort of characteristics  of an entity then please **stop** (don't store delimited values in the database) and normalize your data by creating many-to-many table `entity_fruits`.

Answer (score 1):

You must add

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE <coloumn name> LIKE '%$fruit%'
```

Comment: sorry edit my question to be a bit more clear, that was just a typo

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$where='';
$fruit="apples fruit2";
$arr=explode(" ",$fruit);
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
{
if($i==0)
    $where=$where." LIKE '%".$arr[$i]."%'";
else
    $where=$where." AND  fruitcolumn LIKE '%".$arr[$i]."%'";
}

echo "SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE fruitcolumn  ".$where;
```